# How to install libdoc2testbench on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, robotframework

libdoc2testbench is a tool of Robot Framework which supports importing test results to imbus testbench. Due to Robot Framework documentation, it is to be installed by
pip install robotframework-libdoc2testbench

I want to install it on Ubuntu 18.04; there I get the error:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework-libdoc2testbench (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for robotframework-libdoc2testbench

Best regards
Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling `pip` from Python 2.7.

Make sure you use Python 3, for example with:

```
python3 -m pip install robotframework-libdoc2testbench
```

EDIT: You can download the .wheel or source tar from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-libdoc2testbench/#files) and install with pip pointing to it (and then if needed, download other required packages).

However the solution to your problem is the Python version. From the [project page](https://github.com/imbus/robotframework-libdoc2testbench), we see it needs Python 3.7.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. Unfortunately it does not work in my environment: It causes the same error.
I have installed python 2.7 and python 3.6 and a link python -> python 3.6, so python --version responds version 3.6.
And I also explicitely called pip as you described. Result:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework-libdoc2testbench (from versions: none)
Only difference to previous execution is "(from versins: none)" instead of "(from versions: )"

Comment: I forgot to say: Maybe the reason is the proxy restriction in the company network. Other installatins have worked, including robotframework and its libraries, maybe here is a difference.
Can you provide me a amd64.deb file (for Ubuntu 18.04), that I can download and install locally from the file?